# Regular Expression to find querystring portion of a hyperlink

Tags: .net, regex

I'm pretty new to regular expressions, but I'm sure a regex would give me something much more elegant than anything I could do with string methods.

I've got a hyperlink in the form of:

```
<a href="http://server.com/default.aspx?abc=123">hello</a>
```

I want to yank out just the querystring portion.  Also, what's a good reference for .net regular expressions (sheepish grin)? I find the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) very hard to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following code will extract the query string

```
string html = "<a href=\"http://server.com/default.aspx?abc=123\">hello</a>";
Match m = Regex.Match(html, "<a[^>]+href=\".*?\\?(.*?)\">");
string querystring = m.Groups[1].ToString();
```

regex explained:

```
take only strings starting with <a href="
between the a and href there can be other attributes, spaces, it ignores them
make a group of the the url, from the first question mark to the ending quotes - this is your query string
```

Answer (score 1):

For regex development, I recommend [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm). As for the regex itself, search the ? and match until the next ".

Answer (score 1):

```
 /<a\s+href="[^?]+\?(.*)">/
```

or even this should work:

```
/\?(.+)"/
```

Edit: watchout for greediness.. For laziness (in case there are other attributes), use this.

```
/\?(.+?)"/
```

Thanks @Guffa

Comment: Make it /\?(.+?)"/ so that it stops at the first quoation mark, in case there are more attributes after the href.

Comment: I wud further modify it to /\?([^\s]*?)"/ - because http://server.com/default.aspx?  (empty query string) is still a valid URL

Comment: /href=".*\?([^\s]*?)"/ -- modified to accommodate ? in previous attributes as in '<a title="click?sure" href="server.com/default.aspx?asd=e3" id="asd">hello</a>'

Comment: Better use `/<a\s+href="[^"?]*\?([^"]*)">/`.

Comment: @Gumbo wudn't that fail if href is not the first attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a regular expression, couldn't you just use the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class, specifically the [`Uri.Query`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query.aspx) property?

Example:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://server.com/default.aspx?abc=123");
Console.WriteLine(uri.Query);
```

Prints:

> `?abc=123`

Comment: Good suggestion.  This should be doable too.  But it sounds like he still needs to parse the HTML file to get the link to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something simple?

```
/\?([^\"]+)\"/
```

It'd match `abc=123`.

Comment: Don't u need a + after the character class [] ?

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work

```
(?<=href="[^"]+\?)[^"]+
```

[Here it is with test cases in Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=3e91ffc5-57f4-4098-8e7e-8438bc61d8b5). (You can also use this tool to generate .NET code for you.)

And as for a reference, I'm working on a clean & concise [.NET regex reference](http://regexhero.net/reference/).  It's not quite done but it's pretty close.  You can also click a regular expression to see an example  slide down with a neat jQuery animation, but I digress.

And then there's a more detailed reference site at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ with quick references as well as a narrative style to explain everything.